# Why ant build fails with proguard enabled?

Tags: android, ant

I'm using the standard generated build.xml file for ant builds.
It builds with success when I type `ant debug`, but when I run the `ant release` command it fails. I guess it is related to proguard rules, however it builds with success on eclipse in release mode.

How can I configure it to work properly with proguard?

Here is the exception I got.

> [proguard] Optimizing...
>
> BUILD FAILED C:\android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:875:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value is not a reference value
>   [proguard.evaluation.value.Instru ctionOffsetValue]
>           at proguard.evaluation.value.Value.referenceValue(Value.java:97)
>           at proguard.optimize.evaluation.SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.isPoppingSimpleEnum(SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.java:530)
>           at proguard.optimize.evaluation.SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.isPoppingSimpleEnum(SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.java:520)
>           at proguard.optimize.evaluation.SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.visitVariableInstruction(SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.java:229)
>           at proguard.classfile.instruction.VariableInstruction.accept(VariableInstruction.java:306)
>           at proguard.optimize.evaluation.SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.visitCodeAttribute(SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.java:131)
>           at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
>           at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
>           at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
>           at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
>           at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
>           at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
>           at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
>           at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
>           at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:124)
>           at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:373)
>           at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:306)
>           at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:115)
>           at proguard.ant.ProGuardTask.execute(ProGuardTask.java:316)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>           at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Comment: Paste your proguard.txt file please

Comment: @Pauland https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22928439/proguard-project.txt

Comment: @Pauland also note that I use it with proguard-android-optimize.txt

Comment: try to use only proguard-android-optimize, to see if the problem persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

The issue was related to proguard version which I updated to 4.11

Reverted back to 4.7 and it started to work!

Comment: Had the same problem. Rolling back to 4.7 resolved my issue. For what it's worth, I did not try a version between 4.7 and 4.11.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug with ProGuard version 4.11.

http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/505/

Instead of downgrading, an alternative solution can be to turn off the particular optimization causing the problem.

Include this line in your proguard file:

`-optimizations !class/unboxing/enum`

Comment: Thank you sir! Just ran into this bug and was looking for the disable for the optimization which was crashing.